# How to configure a Service Provider in Ping Federate

Tags: pingfederate

I am new to Ping Federate. I have developed SAML 2.0 SSO browser profile code from an application. Tested it using WSO2 Identity Server. It works in PingFederate too. But I am facing hard time figuring out the pieces of puzzle in PingFederate.

Please point me to a good resouce on this.

Thanks

Comment: Typically, our customers use an integration kit (agentless, Java/OpenToken, for example) or OAuth for last mile integration with an application. It sounds like, however, that you've built your app to consume SAML.. As such, what it is that you're trying to do is unclear. Please clarify the question.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Basically we have a J2EE web application which needs to support SAML2 / OAuth2 Single Sign On any standard Identity/Federation server. Have it working on WSO2 Identity server and works on PingFed in our client end. But I am trying to configure PingFed at my end.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are trying to configure in PingFed... Are you trying to play the role of an IdP and creating an SP Connection?

Comment: I am trying to create an SP Connection

Answer (score 0):

Ping has a video in their library [here](https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/ping_sm_videoLibrary/page/pf_creatingConnectionIdP.html) that describes creating an SP connection.

Comment: I followed the video. The problem is that whenever I am getting redirected to PingFederate login screen, I am getting error. 

Exception message is : No SSO profile configured for ubuntu:default:entityId to start the SSO process

If you can point out to some tutorial , it will be great help. Pretty packed up to go through the big PingFederate documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I went over your video library. The video are based on old version of PingFederate server. I am using 8.2.2.1 . Please point out to the latest version of the video tutorials if you know off. Thanks

Comment: While the videos are of an older version, overall, the process remains the same. What are you struggling with?